# How to add scripts (AS3) to a project?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs3

I am using Adobe Flash CS3 with Actionscript 3.0. What are the different ways to add scripts to a project except adding the script to a new keyframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [document class](http://www.heaveninteractive.com/weblog/2008/03/04/introduction-to-the-document-class-in-actionscript-30-tutorial/), which lets your scripts reside exclusively in files (instead of on the frame).

This is the only other method that I am aware of for linking code to a project in the Flash authoring tool.

**UPDATE:**
As others have mentioned, you can also specify a class to link your library assets to (I had forgotten about this :-). This lets you add custom behaviour when creating instances of your assets; for example, you can link a MovieClip asset to a class that extends MovieClip. Then, whenever you instantiate instances of that asset in your code, they will have all the behaviour of the linked class.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a document class, as Cameron suggest, is a good starting point. That class (the main class, if you will) can then import and use other classes.

You can also specify classes for library items (Properties/Linking/Export for ActionScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Document Class field to specify a class for the whole stage, or, if you want some modularity, you can *link* a library symbol to a specific class too.

The Linkage property is available in the Properties of a symbol from the library, checking the Export For Actionscript checkbox and filling the Class field.

If you want a functionality similar to the "main" function of the other programming languages, the Document Class is the way to go. Otherwise, link a symbol to the class of your liking and put it in stage manually.